# Directory of files (dataframes) in workspace in pycharm (python, pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pycharm, workspace

I'm working with sensitive data and are interested in the location of the dataframes in the workspace. Evidently, the dataframes must be stored somewhere, even though it's only a temporary file, but where? And is the directory changeable.

I'm a statistician and maybe I don't get some basic concepts of computer science.

Thank you very much!

[image: Pycharm workspace with the import of sas-dataset]

Comment: Not sure I understand, you're asking where the DF itself is during runtime?
If so it is saved in-memory, it is not saved to anywhere on the file system, but kept in memory of the running program

Comment: Ahh, ok. I think that was the answer, I was looking for. I'm gonna read more about, though. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you do want to save it to a file (so that it will exist even after the run) you have many options to do that, you can take a look at the Pandas documentation for `to_excel` for example

Comment: True! I was concerned about the location of the workspace data, beacuase the data I want to import to python is sensitive and shouldn't leave a specific server. I'm working with python on my local computer, and didn't wnat anything to be stored there. But I guess everything in the programs "in-memory" is deleted when the program is terminated? :)

Comment: Exactly. Any program's memory is "deleted" when the program exits, gracefully or not. The only way to persist files is to save them to any external persistent system (a hard drive, for example)